# Prove that the set $A:=\{ x : 0 \le f(x) \le 1 \}$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove the following:

Suppose that $f : D \to R$ is continuous with $D$ compact. Prove that  $\{ x : 0 \le f(x) \le 1 \}$ is compact.

My attempt:

We define

$$A:=\{ x : 0 \le f(x) \le 1 \}$$

We have to prove that:

1) $A$ is bounded

2)$A$ is closed

For the first part we note that $A \subset D$, and given that D is compact, $D$ is bounded, then $A$ is bounded.

But for second part I am stuck because I do not know how can it help me that $f$ is continuous, Can you help me to prove this please? I really need you help, thank you.

**well  I have this for the second part: We consider a sequence {xn}→x, x∈D because D is compact , then because of the continuity of f we have that {f(xn)}→f(x) but there I dont know how to argue that x∈A thank you**

Comment: This depends on what you already know about continuity. If you know inverse images of open sets are open, then you can say that inverse images of closed sets are closed by noting that the inverse image of a complement is the complement of the inverse image.

Comment: Well in fact we havent seen this part already :), how can I do it with out this? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hint: given continuity, inverse images of closed sets are closed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach–it is well known that the following are equivalent:

- $f$ is continuous
- $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for every open set $U$
- $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed for every closed set $V$

The set $A$ you describe can be written as $A = f^{-1}([0,1])$.

---

Otherwise, try to show that $A$ contains it's limit points.

That is: suppose that $x_n$ is a sequence of elements in $A$ with $x_n \to x$. Show (using the continuity of $f$) that $x$ must be an element of $A$.

**Regarding the first part:** Note that compact doesn't mean "closed and bounded" for all metric spaces. However, we do know that closed subsets of compact sets are compact, so you are correct in you supposition that it is enough to prove that A is closed.

That is, the first part of your answer could simply be the sentence "closed subsets of compact sets are compact and $A \subset D$, it suffices to show that $A$ is closed." Then again, if $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then Heine-Borel applies and your approach is valid.

---

**Additional hint:** You've established that $\{f(x_n)\}$ is a sequence (in the closed set $[0,1]$) converging to $f(x)$.  Conclude that $f(x) \in [0,1]$.  What does this tell us about $x$?

Comment: Am I right in the first part ?

Comment: You're a bit off there, actually.  Compact doesn't mean "closed and bounded" for every single metric space.  However, we do know that closed subsets of compact sets are compact, so you are correct in you supposition that it is enough to prove that $A$ is closed.

Comment: If the question says that $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, however, then your approach will do.

Comment: Well then I got confused because the only thing we have In this approach is the Heine-Borel thm we dont know more about compacity on that thm and the def. :) What will happen there tahk you :)

Comment: @user162343 do you have a definition of compactness that is *not* the Heine Borel theorem?  Something to do, perhaps, with either finite subcovers or convergent subsequences?

Comment: @user162343 and again, if we can somehow assume that $D$ is a subset of a metric space where the Heine Borel theorem applies (i.e. $\Bbb R^n$), then your approach is fine.

Comment: well I have this: Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ we say that $E$ is compact if for all open cover of $E$ there exists a finite subcover of $E$.

Comment: Okay, so you have the open-cover definition.  Good.  Then you should also have (somewhere in your textbook or notes) the statement that "closed subsets of compact sets are compact".

Comment: Well We are reading the Gaughan's textbook and there it doesnt say something about it, and neither  in my notes :)

Comment: Well then, don't worry about it.  See my earlier comments; I guess $D\subset \Bbb R^n$

Comment: Ok I will do my homework assuming that :), let me do it and if I get again stuck Can I let you know?, is because this homework has been a little dificult for me :) thank you

Comment: Sure, feel free to let me know.

Comment: well @Omnomnomnom I have this for the second part: We consider a sequence $\{ x_n\} \to x$, $x \in D$ because $D$ is compact , then because of the continuity of $f$ we have that $\{ f(x_n)\} \to f(x)$ but there I dont know how to argue that $x \in A$ thank you

Comment: How can I argue that  x∈A thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for the aditional hint but can I conclude with the argument above that f(x) belongs [0,1]? or I have to argue something else thanks :)

Comment: The set $[0,1]$ is closed. What do you know about convergent sequences and closed sets? Yes, it is possible to conclude that $f(x) \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, they converge to some point of the closed set :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** $\{x:0\le f(x)\le1\}$ is a closed subset (inverse image under a continuous function of a closed set) of a compact set ($D$).

**Hint 2:** Take a look at the [Compact spaces and set operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Properties_of_compact_spaces).